# Mercurial: keep 2 branches in sync but with certain persistent differences?

Tags: django, mercurial

I'm a web developer working on my own using django, and I'm trying to get my head round how best to deploy sites using mercurial. What I'd like to have is to be able to keep one repository that I can use for both production and development work. There will always be some differences between production/development (e.g. they might use different databases, development will always have debug turned on) but by and large they will be in sync. I'd also like to be able to make changes directly on the production server (tidying up html or css, simple bugfixes etc.).

The workflow that I intend to use for doing this is as follows:

- Create 2 branches, prod and dev (all settings initially set to production settings)
- Change settings.py and a few other things in the dev branch. So now I've got 2 heads, and from now on the repository will always have 2 heads.
- (On dev machine) Make changes to dev, then use 'hg transplant' to copy relevant changesets to production.
- push to master repository
- (On production server) Pull from master repo, update to prod head

Note: you can also make changes straight to prod so long as you transplant the changes into dev.

This workflow has the drawback that whenever you make a change, not only do you have to commit it to whichever branch you make the change on, you also have to transplant it to the other branch. Is there a more sensible way of doing what I want here, perhaps using patches? Or failing that, is there a way of automating the commit process to automatically transplant the changeset to the other branch, and would this be a good idea?

Comment: I'll weigh in with an answer below, though Steve L.'s excellent suggestion has already been selected, but I want to point out that independent of how you finally do it, the `transplant` extension is a particularly bad way to do it.

Transplant does an export and then an import, which give your changeset a whole new hash/node id.  If every changeset changes names between development and production you're asking for trouble tracking what got fixed where and where a problem was introduced. Making `hg incoming` and `hg outgoing` unusable between dev and prod is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd probably use Mercurial Queues for something like this.  Keep the main repository as the development version, and have a `for-production` patch that makes any necessary changes for production.

Comment: Mercurial Queues Extension http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension
Mercurial Queues Extention Tutorial http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqTutorial

Answer (score 2):

Here are two possible solutions one using mercurial and one not using mercurial:

1. Use the hostname to switch between prod and devel.  We have a single check at the top of our settings file that looks at the SERVER_NAME environment variable.  If it's www.production.com it's the prod DB and otherwise it picks a specified or default dev/test/stage DB.
2. Using Mercurial, just have a clone that's dev and a clone that's prod, make all changes in dev, and at deploy time pull from dev to prod.  After pulling you'll have 2 heads in prod diverging from a single common ancestor (the last deploy).  One head will have a single changeset containing only the differences between dev and prod deployments, and the other will have all the new work.  Merge them in the prod clone, selecting the prod changes on conflict of course, and you've got a deployable setup, and are ready to do more work on 'dev'.  No need to branch, transplant, or use queues.  So long as you never pull that changeset with the prod settings into 'dev' it will always need a merge after pulling from dev, and if it's just a few lines there's not much to do.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this with local settings.

1. Append to settings.py:

   `try:
   from local_settings import *
   except ImportError:
   pass`
2. `touch local_settings.py`
3. Add `^local_settings.py$` to your `.hgignore`

Each deploy I do has it's own local settings (typically different DB stuff and different origin email addresses).

PS: Only read the "minified versions of javascript portion" later. For this, I would suggest a post-update hook and a config setting (like JS_EXTENSION).

Example (from the top of my head! not tested, adapt as necessary):

1. Put JS_EXTENSION = '.raw.js' in your `settings.py` file;
2. Put JS_EXTENSION = '.mini.js' in your `local_settings.py` file on the production server;
3. Change JS inclusion from:
   `<script type="text/javascript" src="blabla.js"></script>`
   To:
   `<script type="text/javascript" src="blabla{{JS_EXTENSION}}"></script>`
4. Make a post-update hook that looks for `*.raw.js` and generates `.mini.js` (minified versions of raw);
5. Add `.mini.js$` to your `.hgignore`

Comment: This method is pretty tidy. I like the JS_EXTENSION part, does exactly what I wanted and makes sense immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try something like this: (I was just thinking about this issue, in my case it's a sqlite database)

- Add `settings.py` to .hgignore, to keep it out of the repository.
- Take your `settings.py` files from the two separate branches and move them into two separate files, `settings-prod.py` and `settings-dev.py`
- Create a deploy script which copies the appropriate settings-X file to settings.py, so you can deploy either way.

If you have a couple of additional files, do the same thing for them. If you have a lot of files but they're all in the same directory by themselves, you could just create a pair of directories: `production` and `development`, and then either copy or symlink the appropriate one into a `deploy` directory.

If you did something like this, you could dispense with the need for branching your repository.

Comment: I like this approach because of its lack of branches, in fact I use one similar already. Instead of making 2 settings files, I make a settings directory and put an `__init__.py` file in it add my settings files in there, prod.py and dev.py (idea lifted from this blog:http://blog.haydon.id.au/2009/07/django-development-workflow.html). Then just symlink the correct wsgi script in. But unfortunately I need to change some templates as well, production uses minified versions of javascript and dev uses unminified, and I don't think I can do this without some nasty symlinking.

Answer (score 1):

I actually do this using named branches and straight merging instead of transplanting (which is more reliable, IMO). This usually works, although sometimes (when you've edited the different files on the other branch), you'll need to pay attention not to remove the differences again when you're merging.

So it works great if you're not changing the different files much.